# JQL Search to Exclude multiple values in a field

Tags: jql

I am trying to pull a Bug report excluding all Bugs that are in a Done/Closed status.

So far I have this

`"Dev Team[Dropdown]" = "Team name" AND issuetype = Bug AND status != Done ORDER BY priority DESC`

I reviewed several previous posts that do

`"Dev Team[Dropdown]" = "Team name" AND issuetype = Bug AND status != (Done, Closed) ORDER BY priority DESC`

However, that errors out.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`"Dev Team[Dropdown]" = "Team name" AND issuetype = Bug AND status != (Done, Closed) ORDER BY priority DESC`

This particular query will not work because `!=` operators will not support the values of the field status.

Try using this :

`"Dev Team[Dropdown]" = "Team name" AND issuetype = Bug AND status not in (Done, Closed) ORDER BY priority DESC`

Reference :

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/why-my-jql-search-with-not-in-or-not-equals-operators-has-issues-missing-1018766307.html

https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-operators/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the statusCategory field. So something like

`"Dev Team[Dropdown]" = "Team name" AND issuetype = Bug AND statusCategory != Done ORDER BY priority DESC`

If you have "normal" workflows your 'Done' statuses like Done, Cancelled, Rejected, Completed, etc., all have a statusCategory of 'Done' so you can use that to cover all the 'Done' statuses.